# Splitting train and test in multilabel classification to avoid missing data in the train set

Tags: machine-learning

I have a dataset (600 rows) composed of two columns:

-Summary: which contains the text of a document

-Keywords: which contains the keywords that identify that document.

```
                                               Summary                     KeyWords_in_Array_wo_insurance
0    court sanction scheme transfer insur reinsur b...                                       [insolvency]
1    immedi custodi sentenc month week impos direct...  [administration of justice, civil evidence, se...
2    motorist injur hit run collis car identifi dri...                         [negligence, road traffic]
3    claimant given permiss continu claim compani a...                      [insolvency, civil procedure]
4    court gave guidanc approach taken applic relea...                           [civil procedure, costs]
5    plaintiff solicitor entitl declar life critic ...                                           [trusts]
6    claimant insur establish requir standard road ...                           [personal injury, torts]
7    minimum indemn requir institut charter account...  [arbitration, civil procedure, costs, accounta...
8    applic secur cost court could take account eve...          [civil procedure, insolvency, cpr, costs]
```

I want to predict which keywords identify a summary.
The keywords are not mutually exclusive.

My code is:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_final["Summary"], df_final["KeyWords_in_Array_wo_insurance"], test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
y_train_mlb = mlb.fit_transform(y_train)

classifier = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC()))])


classifier.fit(X_train, y_train_mlb)
y_predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)
all_labels = mlb.inverse_transform(y_predicted)

y_test_mlb = mlb.transform(y_test)


print("Accuracy = ", accuracy_score(y_test_mlb,y_predicted))
```

I am getting a low accuracy score: 20%

Therefore I am thinking that my classification is not good enough.

The reason it might be that some keywords are used only once.
For example, the keywords "animal" or "partnership" or "succession" are used only in 1 row. (Meaning, they are assigned to only one summary)

I think, therefore, that when I split the dataset in training and test, some "lonely keywords" enter the test dataset but not the training one. Thus, the model will never be trained on them.

Is this the reason why my accuracy is so low?

Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: In any case, such single instances are not useful, either for training or for testing, and you should probably remove them...

Comment: any particular reason for using `OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC())`?

Comment: It is one of the example I found online, but there is no specific reason behind it

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this is because you don't have a lot of data for all the different classes you are trying to obtain. If you are training something with two classes, you want thousands of text for each. Maybe you don't have that.

Also civil procedure and civil evidence are counted as different classes for you. I would imagine if you lemmatize all of them and make smaller categories (join these two as 'civil' for example) you could get a better result?